# Compass/Sass background-image positioning

Tags: sass, background-image, compass-sass, css-sprites, background-position

When using sprites in Compass/Sass, you get a background-image and a background-position generated.

For example:

```
background: url('../images/generated/bg-sa8e38178a4.png') no-repeat;
background-position: 0 -120px;
```

This background image is positioned in the upper left corner of your element.
With normal CSS I can change this to the bottom right corner like so:

```
background-position: right bottom;
```

However, this doesn't work when using a sprite, as its for the entire sprite instead of each image in my sprite.

How can I tell Compass/Sass to place each image of my sprite in the bottom right corner, instead of upper left?

Note: the element I'm using this sprite on, changes in height, so I can't use fixed pixel values.

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm including this image to illustrate what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify how this would be useful?  The background-position property offsets are from the top left corner (unless the browser supports the 4 value syntax:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

Comment: I've added a picture in my question to illustrate how this could be usefull. Default is on the left, what I want to acomplish on the right.

Comment: Can you manually write out the CSS that will make this work with your Compass generated sprite?  I don't see how what you're asking for is possible from a CSS perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achive this using the **:after** psuedo class on my element.
You need to give the **:after** class a width and height equal to your image, and position it using CSS.

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  /* your element css */

  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url('../images/generated/bg-sa8e38178a4.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -120px;    
}
```